# ALTER specific table which has more than 10 million record

Tags: mysql

I have one table called `History` in which client has more than **10 million** records in it.

Now I want to `ALTER` this table with `New Extra Column`, but it is taking too much time and sometime even server crash.

Is there any faster way by which I can `ALTER` large tables?

My query is :

> ALTER TABLE `History` ADD COLUMN `oldID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL, 
>   ADD INDEX `oldid16` (`oldID`);

I am using `InnoDB`.

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin to alter the table? Try using a client program like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Comment: we are using liquibase migration script.

Comment: The query itself seems fine. The issue I guess to do with the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Workbench db editor there are 3 options, self-explanatory:

- DBMS connection keep-alive interval (in seconds): 600
- DBMS connection read time out (in seconds): 600
- DBMS connection time out (in seconds): 60

If you want to achieve your task in MySQL Workbench, then you have to give higher values to these options.

The same principle should apply to all editors, inclusive Liquibase.

More of it, in MySQL server you can achieve this by changing some server system variables:

- connect_timeout (the most important for your task)
- long_query_time
- wait_timeout
- interactive_timeout
- net_read_timeout
- net_write_timeout

and/or maybe others, I don't know them anymore.

Good luck!

### EDIT 1:

There are also innodb specific variables as candidates for changing, in order to accomplish your task. Like this, for example:

- innodb_buffer_pool_size

All changes and combinations depend, of course, on your system resources/configurations/workflow.

### EDIT 2:

PS: For such very big operations we used [**SQLyog**](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog), a very stable and powerfull db editor. Most important: we had never crashes like with MySQL Workbench. And all db workflows/processes were smooth.

### EDIT 3:

**New suggestions:**

- Prepare the logging process before running the query again, in order to follow the arised error or success messages.
- Also, I saw the query. I would suggest you to apply the `oldid16`
  index separately, after inserting the new column.
- An important one, about the db tables: each of them should have a
  separately file allocated in the file system. See [**InnoDB
  File-Per-Table Tablespaces**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html). And, maybe, [Overview of Partitioning in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html)

P.S: Personally, I can't see another option for running the `ALTER` query in other way, than is presented by your original question: as a whole and at once - after, maybe, separating the `index` part too.

Comment: Actually for on premise customer we can not give an option to run query on SQLyog or workbench. We have to run from cmd. Like migration script. thought I will try your options.

Comment: @RonakPatel Yes, you have right, for the customer should be used the "native" editor. I didn't knew your project constelation. But cmd is an editor, e.g. an interface as the others. Therefore, the same conditions of running `ALTER` query can be applied. The idea of changing server variables are the effect of your statement about server crashes. I'll edit with EDIT 3 now, in order to make new suggestions.

Comment: @RonakPatel I just remembered something: the long time it takes should come from applying the index part, not from adding the column.

Comment: But index is necessary.

Comment: @RonakPatel Of course it's necessary. But you can run a second `ALTER` query for applying the index, AFTER you apply the `ALTER`query for only creating the column.